# How to assign Spark Thrift server connection to queue

Tags: apache-spark, queue

I would like to establish 2 connections to one Spark Thrift Server for each development and QA. These two connections should be passed through 2 independent queues.

To achieve above, I set below properties from beeline when connecting Thrift server.
1) mapred.job.queue.name
2) spark.yarn.queue

Connection URL: jdbc:hive2://host:port?**mapred.job.queue.name=queue_name**

And, executed queries from beeline with above URL. However, I could not able to verify that query is executed with right queue.

Please help.

Thanks,
Sravan

Answer (score 0):

You can check the YARN ResourceManager UI, every application running on top of YARN will be displayed there, also you can use the `yarn application -list` command line to verify which queue is the app assigned to.